# proper steps to mount the hdfs using hadoop fuse

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have been searching for steps to mount hdfs via hadoop fuse
 I tried google results for this but none of them seems to be working.
I am working on Cent OS n have configured chd4 hadoop on 2 nodes one master and a slave.
can anyone please help me wit proper steps for fuse.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the steps which were explained in Cloudera's own document? 
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_28.html

Comment: I did try dat sir but m getting the following error 
http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/redhat/6/i386/cdh/4/RPMS/i386/hadoop-yarn-2.0.0%2B1518-1.cdh4.5.0.p0.24.el6.i686.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'archive.cloudera.com'"
Trying other mirror.


Error Downloading Packages:
  hadoop-client-2.0.0+1518-1.cdh4.5.0.p0.24.el6.i686: failure: RPMS/i386/hadoop-client-2.0.0+1518-1.cdh4.5.0.p0.24.el6.i686.rpm from cloudera-cdh4: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

Comment: Ok it seems as if your dns settings have a problem on that Hadoop node. Try this please, nslookup archive.cloudera.com . If you do not get the IP as 184.73.217.71 then please edit that nodes /etc/resolv.conf and add nameserver 8.8.8.8 to it. Then, please retry.

Comment: thank you sir, i installed fuse successfully.
Aftr installtion and making an entry in /etc/fstab,when I fire mount <mountpoint_name> it says No such file or directory.
Also the ls command on <mountpoint_name> says No such file or directory.

Comment: Did you create the mount point with mkdir command? Mount point should exist before mounting. Also when you are mounting to that folder, you should give the full path if you aren't in the same directory.

Comment: $ hadoop-fuse-dfs dfs://masterganesh:50070 /home/hadoopmount 
/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/fuse_dfs: error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
This is wat error I am getting. I created the mountpoint with make directory.

Comment: It is related to your link library setup. You need to export your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable as the following example. Of course change the arch and path to suit your OS and machine.

    `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/i386/client`

Comment: "$ /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/lib/i386/" my java path is this so i added
"export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/lib/i386:/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/lib/i386/client" to the /etc/ld.so.conf
file but it gives an error when i run ldconfig as  "ldconfig: /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/lib/i386:/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/lib/i386/client is not a known library type"